# What does this symbol in the "Admin Summary" page mean?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

In the summary of the monthly activities done from moderators, I see a symbol close to my name.

[image: screenshot]

The used symbol is the one that on *Drupal Answers* is used for the bronze badge, but it seems also the color used for values that are 50% or less of the median, which doesn't seem my case, if that is referring to my activities.

What does that symbol exactly mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just hover over it to get the tooltip, it means you have the talkative badge (for posting 10 messages with 1 or more starred in chat) on the site. The Outspoken badge is also displayed at this position.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It refers to the chat.

Comment: Sigh! It's the usual problem with the tooltips I have. It is good to know there are other badges shown there. Do I take only chat related badges are shown there?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, only those two chat-related flags